# sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467"

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an android facebook app and have the app id, but I have not released it yet.
The problem I am facing is that when I have the facebook app on the device and I am signing into my app using it for SSO, I am successfully signed in but while trying to share a post the facebook dialog screen appears asking me to sign in again and the logcat says:

```
sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
```

this does not happen when I uninstall the facebook app. I sign into my app by signing in through facebook and then easily share and post.

Is this problem because my app I have not yet released and the facebook is not granting me access to its database and thus I am being asked to signing again through my apps dialog? or is it due to some other reason??

i m having another app in google play nd the same code runs perfectly for that app...i had added the sso feature to it many days after i had already published it

Comment: See weather your database is created or not.You can check it in your DDMS (i.e. data/data/YouPKGname/database).

Comment: @Akshay the phone data folder in file-explorer in ddms does not expand...so i m unable to check it out... howerver the data folder for the emulators expand properly but i cant install the official fcbk app on an emultor nd test it then..

Comment: You can check it on emulator.It will not open data folder in the phone.